# Redirect to a URL without showing the URL

Tags: c#, proxy, redirect

I have a URL to a mp3 file . I need to redirect to the mp3 file without showing the URL because it contains my API key; is there a way to do this?

I don't want the client/sniffer to read my URL.

Can someone please provide a code snippet that I can look at ?

Thanks

Comment: Well.. are you doing something in C#?  what code have you tried?  You could create a service that serves up this file so it hides your authentication...

Comment: i tried serponse.redirect which obviously dosent work , and server.transfer which is not of much use to me coz its a mp3 file on the other end.

Comment: the answers given are on the right track.. you need to manage the user the whole way along, not just send them to the file. serve the file to them instead

Comment: In ASPX you can write data into the response stream directly (not sure what platform your using here). This is one way we handle not having to even save auto-generated PDFs. If you can figure out how to tell the browser to download/play the content then you don't have to expose anything.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this by redirecting the request, since a redirect will tell the client where to get the file.

The best solution would be to use a proxy application on a server where your users don't have direct access. This proxy software would then load the .mp3 from its original source and forward the data to your client. The API key you want to protect will never leave the server. However, you will need to control access to your proxy by some means.

If you are referring to a client side application: There will always be a possibility to get the URL out of the application. It depends on your threat model. Whom are you protecting the API key against? If you have highly skilled attackers in mind, it's likely that they will be able to extract the key from your application.

Anyway it is a good idea to use encrypted connections when transferring credentials. If you are using `https://` and checking the certificates you will at least defend yourself against sniffing the network traffic.

Comment: can u lead me to a webpage or code i can look at . This is first time i am dealing with such stuff :(

Comment: What parts can you alter? Do you have your own server? Or do you just have the client application?

Comment: i only have a client application

Comment: may be just not totally visible is fine . Like may be not page source/ URL.

Comment: OK, it looks like we don't fully understand your question. Please try to tell us more on your desired architecture. Where do you want to hide the URL? Who creates the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no way to prevent sniffing your actual code. Developing a proxy URL on your own site will prevent them to access your API key, but you may need a large bandwidth.

Comment: can u lead me to a code which lets me do such stuff like creating a proxy? i saw MSDN but the example dint help much :(

Comment: I Think the simplest solution would be to set up a stand alone proxy software on your server and redirect all download request to it. This way you may just need to make some justification on your code to redirect file download request to that proxy software

Answer (score 0):

if you use routing in MVC or web api you can avoid this kind of redirecting

Comment: How? Can you explain in more detail, to flesh out your answer?